# How to ignore an output of a multi-output function in Python?

Tags: python, function, output

Suppose I have a function:

```
def f():
  ...
  ...
  ...
  return a,b,c
```

and I want to get only b in output of the function. Which assignment I have to use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can unpack the returned tuple into some dummy variables:

```
_, keep_this, _ = f()
```

It doesn't have to be `_`, just something obviously unused.

(Don't use `_` as a dummy name in the interactive interpreter, there it is used for holding the last result.)

Alternatively, index the returned tuple:

```
keep_this = f()[1]
```

Comment: Beat me to it by a couple seconds! Darn!

Comment: I cannot find any documentation for dummy variables. Any helps?

Comment: @Naji basically, what the code does is assign the three parts of the tuple to three variables. A single underscore is a valid variable name, and it can be assigned multiple times in one destructuring assignment. So when that assignment is complete, you will have two variables: keep_this, which equals the middle value in the tuple, and _, which (if I'm correct) equals the last value in the tuple. You should look up destructuring assignment to learn more.

Comment: There is nothing special about these variables. You could write `x, y, z = f()` and just ignore `x` and `z`. The name `_` is just unlikely to be useful for anything else.

Comment: But then this is really not a good method. I might have a function which in certain situations returns a huge matrix but I rarely need it to be returned. Every time assigning a variable to it is not cool!

Comment: @PavelAnossov in a lot of functional programming languages, the name _, when it appears in a pattern, acts as a wildcard. In Python, _ is just another variable name, but in other languages, it has special meaning.

Comment: If your function returns a huge matrix that matrix already exists (unlike lazy evaluation such as Haskell uses); you can discard your reference to it with `del _` if you wish. BTW, `_` is a special variable in the interactive interpreter, holding the last returned value.

Comment: @Naji The function will return everything it has to return, you can't do anything about it. If it returns a matrix, and you need only a single value from it, use the second method.

Answer (score 4):

```
def f():
    return 1,2,3
```

here, `f()` returns a tuple `(1,2,3)` so you can do something like this:

```
a = f()[0]
print a
1

a = f()[1]
print a
2

a = f()[2]
print a
3
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing with the `return a,b,c` line is creating a `tuple` and then returning it from the function. So you can use tuple deconstruction to get only the values you want from the result. Example:

```
def f(x):
    return x, x + 1, x + 2
_, b, _ = f(0)
print(b) # prints "1"
```

Comment: As a side question, why is the code all on one line? I entered it on several lines...

Comment: You somehow managed to put a [SOH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Start-of-Header#SOH) (0x01, CTRL-A) character in there.

Comment: I'm not sure how I managed to do that!